# SQL Group by and intersect between internal columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, set, database-performance

I have below Table Structure

```
Source| Category         |Tag1Value     | Tag2Value
1-q1  | Engagement Type  | Micro Audit  |Audit
1-q1  | Engagement Type  | Micro Audit  |Micro Audit
1-q1  | Industry         | Insurance    |Insurance
```

I want to identify for each category all Tag1Value s are there in Tag2Values are not is there any set based approach by grouping and intersecting the results Please help. There is an iterative approach but I'm looking for a more performing solution as data is in Millions.

Comment: Select one DBMS you are using. What is the expected output?

Comment: And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The expected Output is source which doesn't have at least one Tag2value that is not having tag2value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Category, Tag1Value
FROM table_name t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE Tag2Value = t1.Tag1Value)
```

> UPDATE

Try this :

```
SELECT res.Category, res.tag, COUNT(res.tag) 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Category, Tag1Value tag
    FROM table_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT Category, Tag2Value tag
    FROM table_name) res
GROUP BY res.Category, res.tag
HAVING COUNT(res.tag)>1
```

It return :

```
category          |    tag
-----------------------------------
Industry          |    Insurance
Engagement Type   |    Micro Audit
```

Comment: This is a good answer. But the Key is performance i need to search through same table twice and sub query executes every time for the outer query.

Comment: try my new answer

Comment: Perfect  Touzene Mohamed Wassim  Just a Quick question grouping by multilple columns would it be performing ?? because i need multiple columns in Select list

Comment: you can see execution plan to see the cost of the request when you use multiple column in grouping by.